# Request is missing required authentication credential when try to call google-api oauth2

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api

I sending my access_token via payload in postman like this, to get information like email, name at my backend.:

```
{
    "access_token": "my-google-acces-token"
}
```

In backend, i try to send this access_token to a google request like this:

```
response = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo',
                        headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token_data}'})
```

And i get this response:

```
{
      "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
      }
    }
```

what i doing wrong? my google-acess-token is right

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the value of `access_token_data`, for example, when the value of `access_token_data` is `{"access_token": "my-google-acces-token"}`, I think that such error occurs. If my understanding is correct, please modify `headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token_data}'}` like `headers={'Authorization':  'Bearer my-google-acces-token'}`. Please use the value of `my-google-acces-token`. I commented this because I'm not sure whether my understanding of your issue is correct. I apologize for this.

Comment: Where are you getting access_token_data,  how are you parsening it out?  Remember access tokens are only good for an hour.    Why not use the google api python client, and the people api?  the userinfo endpoint is not guaranteed to always return the user claims that's what the people endpoint is.